# Regex to check a DEFINE set of number that has "E" exponential in it

Tags: regex

I trying find a regex which can satisfy my requirements for finding a set of numbers.

What is valid:

1. Number should be positive
2. All the digits should be `9`

   - After or before decimal. Like, `9999.9999` `9999` `9999999999.9`
   - `9999.0000` `9999.99000` is also valid because `0` after decimal doesn’t count
   - `9999.` is also valid for me
   - Number like `999999.8` `999999998` `99999990.9` `99990000` is invalid because it has different number in it
3. The number should be greater than or equal to `9999`

   - `999.9999` `99` is invalid number

Till now everything was working as expected with `^[9]{4,}\.[9]*[0]*$` this.

---

Later I found out, I may have exponential representation of that number.
Beauty with exponential number it will not have any trailing Zeros(`0`). So there is no chance of getting number like `1.1230000e5`. This will be always be represented as `1.123e5`.

---

Other conditions remains same. I wrote something like this `^[9]\.[9]{3,}[eE][0-9]*$`

But this is not working on most of the cases.
Number `9.999E2`(= 9.999 * 10<sup>2</sup> = 999.9) is invalid for me but the above regex says it's valid.

So found a pattern.
If the number of `9`'s after the decimal is `N`, power of exponent should be always be between `3 to N` (inclusive)

> 9.99999e`M` : No of 9's after decimal 5. Here possible values of `M` are 3 (9999.99), 4 (99999.9) and 5 (999999). `M` can’t be 6 (9999990 invalid number).

Is there any way to modify this regrex `^[9]\.[9]{3,}[eE][0-9]*$` so that I can achieve my requirements?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt a "sledgehammer" approach
^[9].(([9]{3}[eE][3])|([9]{4}[eE][3-4])|([9]{5}[eE][3-5]))$
where the list of alternatives can be extended as appropriate.
Possible solutions depend on where the regex is being called. For example, if invoked from a language such as Perl or Python, would allow a programmed solution in conjunction with regex.

Comment: Im going to use it in Hive query. And `sledgehammer` wouldn’t make sense because number of digit is not limited. If nothing works then I might have to go to programmed approach using UDF.